# Two Arrays from one text file

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash

I have been completely stumped by this one. I have a piece of code that spits out this...

```
192.168.0.1=12345
192.168.0.2=35345
192.168.0.3=72345
192.168.0.4=43345
```

That is written to a text file then loaded back into a program into an array.

Is there a way to split it into 2D array? The first D containing the IP address the second the other numbers. I will need to find out the IP that is linked to the numbers later in the code.

So far I just have this...

```
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'uparray=($(cat ./uptime.txt))'
```

I should probably mention this is running on Raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your bash version supports associative array

```
declare -A ip_nums
while IFS== read ip num; do
    ip_nums[$num]=$ip
done <./uptime.txt
```

then to retreive ip from num

```
echo "${ip_nums[$num]}"
```

EDIT: To memorize the biggest number in the loop

```
biggest=0
while ...
    ...
    if ((num>biggest)); then
        biggest=$num
    fi
done ...
```

Comment: Currently the script checks all the numbers and see which one is bigger, is there an easy way to incorporate an associative array into this. How, after comparing all the numbers together and getting the largest, can I do highip=192.168.0.2? If this is too complex I will make another question :)